# Why Android doesn't find my Activity?

Tags: java, android, class, exception

I am working on an Android Application and I am getting this on the log:

```
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.protocolanalyzer.andres.LogicAnalizerActivity
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at com.multiwork.andres.MainMenu.<clinit>(MainMenu.java:37)
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2220)
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1250)
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5238)
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
06-13 15:35:11.140: E/AndroidRuntime(21290):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

You can see Android is not finding my class com.protocolanalyzer.andres.LogicAnalizerActivity when I try to run it, which seems pretty weird, all my Activities run great, but this specific one is giving me this error. Here is how I start Activities from my ListView:

```
private static final Class<?>[] className = {LCView.class, FrecView.class,
        LogicAnalizerActivity.class, BrazoRobot.class, PruebaParser.class};

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainMenu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MenuNames));

@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if(DEBUG) Log.i("MainMenu", "onListItemClick() - Position: " + position);

        Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, className[position]);
        startActivity(mIntent);
    }
```

An it is my LogicAnalyzerActivity, you can see the package and name are the correct one:

```
package com.protocolanalyzer.andres;

public class LogicAnalizerActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements OnActionBarClickListener, OnNewBluetoothDataReceived{
```

And the Manifest.xml:

```
<activity
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:name="com.protocolanalyzer.andres.LogicAnalizerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

What is happening? I tried:

- Reinstalling app
- Wipping phone data
- Restarting Eclipse
- Cleaning Project
- Using `com.protocolanalyzer.andres.LogicAnalizerActivity.class` instead of `LogicAnalizerActivity.class` in the array

Comment: did you update adt to rev 22?

Comment: Yes I am using the latest ADT through Check For Updates menu

Comment: have you referenced actionbar sherlock library in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have updated adt to rev 22 try the below

Right click on your project goto properties. Java Build Path. Choose Order export tab. Make sure that Android Private Libraries is selected. If you have referenced library project. Do the same for the library project also. Clean and Build.

Answer (score 3):

Your AndroidManifest.xml file says `android:name="com.protocolanalyzer.andres.LogicAnalizerPrefs"`, but the class you need there is actually `android:name="com.protocolanalyzer.andres.LogicAnalizerActivity"`.

Comment: Sorry typing error, it is LogicAnalizerActivity in my manifest